mvn command to skip surefire tests is not working
I'm running this command:
mvn clean verify -U -Dskip.surefire=true -Dskip.integration=true -Pwipedb

but it gives me this error:
Unknown lifecycle phase ".surefire=true". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin
-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: pre-clean, clean, post-clean, validate, initialize, gener
ate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate
-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

I tried alternative command:
mvn clean verify -U -DskipTests=true -DskipITs=true -Pwipedb

but this didn't skip tests.

Try -Dmaven.test.skip=true

If you're using PowerShell, then you might be running into this (also see this). Try surrounding any system property arguments that contain . in quotes.

This is the correct syntax:
mvn -DskipTests <build_phase or plugin:goal>

